# Client side errors logging to the server by using only angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html, css

I am new in angularjs and i want to create client side error/ exception logger (.log/ .js) file to server by using only angularjs. I do not want to use jquery.

Any help will be apprreciable

Answer (score 2):

In angularJS you log with `$log`

```
angular.module('logExample', [])
.controller('LogController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {
  $scope.$log = $log;
  $scope.message = 'Hello World!';
}]);
```

[see here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$log)

As far as I know, you won't be able to write in a file on the server without writing server side code. To send local log to server, use `$http` as follows

```
$http({   url: "log/logExample.txt",
                        method: "PUT",
                        params: angular.toJson({
                            url: $window.location.href,
                            message: 'hello world',
                            type: "debug"
                        })
                    });
```

Comment: i want to store error messages in one file not in console

Comment: can u please explain by using one html example??? Write one code that will help me.
Thanks for help

Comment: plz show us what you tried, so we'll be able to edit it in order to help u